# MySQL TABLE.TABLE_ROWS is decreasing during an insert

Tags: mysql, rdbms

If I issue the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;

INSERT INTO bar SELECT * FROM foo;
```

There are several million rows in foo, so this action takes some time.

If I do the following query repeatedly during the execution of the above:

```
use information_schema
select table_name,  TABLE_ROWS  from tables where table_name IN ('foo','bar');
```

I've seen the following progression:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+
| table_name                      | TABLE_ROWS |
+---------------------------------+------------+
| foo                             |   21270328 |
| bar                             |    5292482 |
+---------------------------------+------------+
```

and then a little later:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+
| table_name                      | TABLE_ROWS |
+---------------------------------+------------+
| foo                             |   21270328 |
| bar                             |    3422182 |
+---------------------------------+------------+
```

Why does this number decrease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the documentation for [information_schema.tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html), "For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization."

Comment: RTFM... My bad.  Thanks for the answer. Nonetheless, it is interesting that it is decreasing.